# Android Media Player lagging

Tags: android

I have to Playlist of songs by fetching them from the server. I am using MediaPlayer OnCompletionListner to play the next song. But each time it taking time to connect to the server. Which feels like lagging in playing in audio. Is there any solution to play files from the server one after another without ant lag.?

Comment: better to use exo player instead of mediaplayer

Comment: Like @MuhammadFarhanArif said, I think Exoplayer is preferential for your use-case. However, you can also try a hack like preloading the next song shortly before the current one ends.